# Помогите с небольшой оптимизацией кода в C#?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, я только начинаю изучать C#, поэтому прошу изъяснять все довольно просто. Есть такой кусок кода и мне кажется что его можно как-то оптимизировать, прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

```
public static void Stats(int Time, int Money, int Coolness, int Cooking)
{
    Console.WriteLine("+--------------------+\n" +
                      "You are living: " + Time + " hours\n" +
                      "You have: " + Money + " roubles\n" +
                      "Coolness level: " + Coolness +" lv\n" +
                      "Cooking level: " + Cooking + " lv\n" +
                      "+--------------------+");
}

public static void Info(int Time, int Money, int Coolness, int Cooking, string msg)
{
    Stats(Time, Money, Coolness, Cooking);
}
```

Comment: а что вам не нравится в вашем коде?

Comment: ты ошибаешься, данный код уже некуда оптимизировать

Comment: Просто мне постоянно приходится прописывать параметры какие я передаю в метод Support.Stats(config.Time, config.Money, config.Coolness, config.Cooking);

Comment: Передавать слишком много параметров в методы не есть хорошо. Так что можно собрать их в класс или структуру.

Comment: @Gardes пять параметров это много? `Так что можно собрать их в класс или структуру.` - а в класс  передавать данные через конструктор с 4-мя параметрами? :))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Роберт Мартин в своей книге "Чистый код" говорит что много)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вы имеете ввиду улучшение дизайна кода (оно же [рефакторинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)), а не оптимизации. [Оптимизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) кода - это ускорение его работы.

Как пишут в комментариях: не стоит передавать много параметров в метод, а лучше сгруппировать в класс. Чем такой подход лучше? Если представить, что добавится ещё одно поле, то придётся везде добавлять это поле. Поэтому в качестве улучшение этого кода предложу следующее:

```
public class Output
{
    public static string GetStats(Stat stat)
    {
        // Для большого количества строк вместо "+" лучше использовать StringBuilder
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine("+--------------------+");
        builder.AppendLine($"You are living: {stat.Time} hours");
        builder.AppendLine($"You have: {stat.Money} roubles");
        builder.AppendLine($"Coolness level: {stat.Coolness} lv");
        builder.AppendLine($"Cooking level: {stat.Cooking} lv");
        builder.AppendLine("+--------------------+");
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var stat = new Stat
        {
            Time = 10,
            Cooking = 2,
            Coolness = 5,
            Money = 2
        };
        var statistics = GetStats(stat);
        Console.WriteLine(statistics);
    }
}

public class Stat
{
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public int Coolness { get; set; }
    public int Cooking { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Почему то Xamarinn studio пишет что такого метода не обнаружено (StringBuilder())

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил что необходимо добавить using System.text

Comment: Если уж через StringBuilder (что правильно), то используйте строго типизированные перегрузки Append(value), вместо добавления строк с интерполяцией, которая вам еще и боксинг для ValueType параметров добавляет. И в общем то, можно заранее задать размер StringBuider, немного с запасом, если формат строки фиксирован. Это избавит от расходов на ресайз внутреннего массива биледра.